# Do I recieve sins for a friend calling me a "god" at a game

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, sin, shirk, kufr

So basically we play a videogame and he called me "god"(for being good at it) which is what I immediately reacted to and told him not to as I am but a human..Could I somehow receive sins from his shirk,as I never even had anything to do with it..It was his saying.He is an ignorant about shirk also.

Jazakullahu Kharian

Answer (score 1):

> The Prophet (ﷺ) heard someone praising another and exaggerating in his praise. The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "You have ruined or cut the man's back (by praising him so much)." ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/52/27))

The hadith is only about praise. What you mentioned is worse.

You should discourage your friend from saying anything like it again, and seek forgiveness for yourself in case you took it to heart even if unknowingly or became proud of it.